# Как установить запрет на доступ к папкам и файлам на сервере?

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, безопасность

Подскажите, как можно установить запрет на доступ к файлам и папкам на серевере для заходов через урл от пользователей. Допустим, есть на сервере несколько папок db - где лежат файлы php для связи с БД, modules - для подключаемых модулей, js - для скрпитов и т.д. Основные файлы - страницы сайта, на которые пользователь может заходить, могут подключать другие файлы из папок modules и db, поэтому прописать в .htaccess что-то вроде DENY ALL или OPTIONS -INDEXES не решает проблему, так как основные файлы-страницы тоже теряют доступ к данным файлам и папкам. Подскажите, как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Что конкретно означает фраза «могут подключать другие файлы»? Как это подключение реализовано?

Comment: @andreymal например, на основном файле - странице есть include 'db/connect.php'; Так вот я хочу чтобы основной файл-страница мог подключать его по необходимости, но пользователи не могли открывать данный файл напрямую указав его в урл.

Comment: Апачевый htaccess никак не влияет на работу php, поэтому deny all должно превосходно работать

Comment: @andreymal да в том-то и дело, что не работает ни так, ни так...

Comment: @andreymal ошибку не пишет. Создаю .htaccess прописываю правило "Deny from all" и "Options -Indexes", закидываю в директорию, которую хочу скрыть. Но все равно, когда в урл прописываю /db/connect.php то спокойно захожу на этот файл, хотя, по идее, не должен...

Comment: Начнём с глупого вопроса: обработка htaccess файлов в вашем апаче вообще включена?

Comment: @andreymal да, это точно